# Mongoose: Find and Sort with no results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I am having issues sorting with mongoose. I am trying to do a find that is returning an empty array, and the sort is crashing

```
jobsHandler.find({'created_at_timestamp_milliseconds': {$gte: timestamp}}).sort({'activity.activity_type':1}).exec(function(err, docs) {
    if(err) {
        return callback(err);
    }
    callback(null, docs);
});
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

I verified that the find returns an empty array:

```
jobsHandler.find({'created_at_timestamp_milliseconds': {$gte: timestamp}}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(result)
})
```

Returns:

> undefined
>
> []

How do you sort when there is a risk of getting no results?

**EDIT**

So that others who reference this question will have more context, the jobHandler was a wrapper around a JobModel mongoose model. Here is the find class:

```
function find(parameters, callback) {
    Job.find(parameters, callback);
}
```

The accepted solution works, because the code is run in the find, and not after the find is complete.

Comment: Is `jobsHandler` a Mongoose model?

Comment: jobsHandler is a mongoose model

Comment: This doesn't make sense; `find` always returns a `Query` object (that has a `sort` method).

Comment: You are right, this is actually because the find I have was a wrapper class around the database. This probably explains why the solution worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
jobsHandler.find({'created_at_timestamp_milliseconds': {$gte: timestamp}},null,{sort:{'activity.activity_type':1}}).exec(function(err, docs) {
if(err) {
    return callback(err);
}
callback(null, docs);
```

});

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this should be equivalent to what the OP was trying and doesn't explain the error they were seeing.

Comment: I have to agree with @JohnnyHK that there's something else going on.